# Как объединить выдачу двух команд в одну строку?

Tags: linux, curl, timestamp

Нужно получать от *curl* ответ в файл + время. Сейчас работает так:

```
$ curl example.com > file
```

Нужно, чтобы в строке с ответом добавилось время, когда был ответ.

Что-то типа:

```
1234567  16:30:13
```

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**обновление**: заменил `>` на `>>`, ввиду появившегося дополнительного требования: добавлять информацию в `file`, а не перезаписывать его каждый раз.

---

например, так:

```
$ { curl example.com | tr -d '\n'; date +' %T'; } >> file
```

`tr -d '\n'` удалит перевод строки из выдачи *curl*-а (если он есть).

Comment: ответ практически верный, нужно добавить -s "example.com". Как сделать чтобы значение не перезаписывалось а вело лог?

Comment: без опции `-s` — если программа `curl` что-то и выведет, то это будет направлено в `stderr`, т.е., в ваш `file` не попадёт.

Comment: чтобы строки добавлялись, надо `>` заменить на `>>`.

Comment: Спасибо за очередную подсказку. Спасибо что всем помогаете на этом портале.